# Use a PHP script to execute a JS <script> tag on the homepage only

Tags: javascript, php, html, surveymonkey

I am trying to create a statement in PHP that will make a survey monkey popup appear on the homepage of a website and not on the other pages.

I've tried the below code and different variations of it to try and get it to work. I can add the popup to the entire site by just putting the  element into the  of the website but when I try to get it to appear only on the homepage, nothing shows up at all.

I've tried it using just one 'echo' instead of splitting it into three and also using /index.php instead of /.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == '/') { 
  echo '<script>';
  echo '(function(t,e,s,o){var n,a,c;t.SMCX=t.SMCX||[],e.getElementById(o)||(n=e.getElementsByTagName(s),a=n[n.length-1],c=e.createElement(s),c.type="text/javascript",c.async=!0,c.id=o,c.src=["https:"===location.protocol?"https://":"http://","widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/tRaiETqnLgj758hTBazgd_2Fw5nxAtNDAAqLsYqzVv_2FShi5yryjY3psD6EYInvUCYX.js"].join(""),a.parentNode.insertBefore(c,a))})(window,document,"script","smcx-sdk");';
  echo '</script>';
 }

?>
```

I have found some similar questions on here but none that quite fit my situation, I've also tried out some of their answers recommendation but they don't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel like it's something so simple and I'm just complicating matters. Hopefully I've provided enough information for you all!

Comment: Maby the `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` returns a value of `null` or `undefined`, try `if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == '/' OR $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == '')`

Comment: Log the output of `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] ` and see what value it has. Then you can compare it to what you have instead of guessing.

Comment: Also, why you calling it with PHP?

Comment: I figured PHP would be the easiest way to write a statement and then execute the script if the condition is correct. The page is written in PHP.

Comment: Ok, have you tried the other solutions above?

Comment: Yes, I did. Your first suggestion just broke the page :(

Comment: @Ember it was without an {  at the end, maby thats the reason? and what was the output of `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`?

Comment: The output was /index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP solution:**

```
$active_location = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
$host_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
if ($active_location == $host_name || $active_location == $host_name.'/'){
//stuff you want to do
}
```

the `$active_location` will return the current full url without the ssl sertivication the `$host_name` wil give the hostname without ssl. if they are the same the code will run.

The `OR (||)` statemant is because in some cases the homepage will will have an `/` without you seeing it, if you don't put the statment the code will not run is some cases.

Comment: Trying this code (the PHP solution) has made the pop appear but on all of the pages instead of just the homepage. The echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; has the output of /index.php

Comment: @Ember Than it will be `if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == '/index.php') { `

Comment: That's what I figured but it's still showing on every page

Comment: @Ember and what is the outcome of `echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];` on the other pages?

Comment: /index.php for all which isn't helpful

Comment: How do you navigate through pages?

Comment: Just via a navigation bar. The pages all have a unique URL

Comment: Try `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`

Comment: That comes up with the url for the selection page so the homepage is 'site.com' and the contact page is 'site.com/contact' for example

Comment: Try: `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']') { `

Comment: Unexpected T_String on that line

Comment: Whoops typo: `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {`

Comment: It happens to the best of us. That just stops the popup from appearing at all. Gonna move this to chat if that's okay :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186720/discussion-between-ember-and-tim567).